# are the solutions of stable $x' = x(1-x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

I had difficulties finding the answer to the following question:

Determine whether the solutions $x(t) = 0$ and $x(t) = 1$ of the single scalar equation $x' = x(1-x)$ are stable or unstable.

I tried to do this with the definition for stability but I wasn't able to find eigenvalues here

Comment: Did you draw the phase portrait? Solutions that have an initial condition in $(0, 1)$ tend towards $1$; what does that tell you about the solutions?

Comment: @Did Thanks, I can't do arithmetic today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Nough said? $$-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!\longleftarrow\!\longleftarrow\!\longleftarrow\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!\stackrel{0}{\otimes}\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!\longrightarrow\!\longrightarrow\!\longrightarrow\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!\stackrel{1}{\otimes}\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-\!\!\longleftarrow\!\longleftarrow\!\longleftarrow\!\!-\!\!-\!\!-$$

Comment: The same result analytically: $f(x)=x(1-x)$, $df/dx=1-2x$, on the solution $x=0$ $df/dx=1>0$, hence it is unstable. On $x=1$, $df/dx<0$, hence, stable.

Comment: @mobiuseng Derivatives are not necessary here, only signs and zeroes matter, and since the function is already written as a product, there is really nothing to do (that is, nothing else than to apply the theorem which is in the OP's notes).

Comment: thanks you very much, as a check for myself, question b) was the same but then with function f(x)= -x(1-x), so f'(x)=2x-1 hence x = 0 is stable and x = 1 is unstable, right?

Comment: Funny, I just explained why derivative is not needed... Anyway, yes, for the dynamics $\dot x=-x(1-x)$, the fixed point $x=1$ is unstable and the fixed point $x=0$ is stable.